Google Ads Retargeting Audiences Not Populating
My audiences in Google Ads are not populating. Purchases, add to carts... are being tracked but not page views.
However, I've checked that my tags are correctly set up through my GTM. The visits are properly reported in GA4.
Could you help me please?
Thank you
I created audiences in GA4 which I find in Google Ads. But they are populating in GA4 and not in Google Ads, even though they are the same audiences.

There are several possible reasons why your Google Ads remarketing audiences aren't filling. To begin, check that your website's Google Ads remarketing tag is correctly implemented and active on all relevant pages. Check that the tag is functioning properly and that there are no tracking or cookie concerns. In addition, ensure that your audience lists are properly configured in Google Ads and that they match the population criteria, such as minimum size and duration of site visits. If everything appears to be in order, it may be worth contacting Google Ads support for more assistance in identifying the issue.
